Whats the best way to run Express VPN through my parental control VPN (Canopy)?
I have a parental control VPN, Canopy, that works very well. However, I also need to run ExpressVPN without bypassing the parental controls. What is the best way of doing this?
I have seen some things here about VPN chaining, but I haven't seen a comprehensive guide or even if it would work in my position.

VPN chaining either requires multiple layers of hardware, or requires an upstream webservice. so if you connect your router to one VPN (outter VPN), and then from a system inside the LAN initiate a VPN connection to the other service (inner VPN), the traffic from the inner VPN will pass through the outer VPN.
